# How to offset addStaticLabels using mapview or leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

How can the labels be moved up, down or to the sides. direction and offset seems to be ignored. I would like my labels to be moved to the bottom.

```
library(mapview);library(leafem)
mapview(franconia)  %>% addStaticLabels(label = franconia$NAME_ASCI, 
                                         style = list(noHide = TRUE,
                                                direction = 'bottom',
                                                textOnly = TRUE,
                                                offset =c(5,7),
                                                color='red'))
```

Comment: See https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues/466#issuecomment-1868902038